# sed - print all lines before the nth occurrence of a string

Tags: bash, sed

Suppose I have:

```
content line 1
content line 2
blabla *my_pattern_str* (1st occurrence)
...
content line x 
blabla *my_pattern_str* (nth occurrence <- I want to print from the beginning line up to here)
content line y
content line y+1
...
```

I would like to print all the lines before and including the nth occurrence of **my_pattern_str**. How can I do this using `sed` (or similar command like `grep` or `awk`)?

Comment: sed is not very strong in count for paragraph. awk is lot better in this kind of solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust `7`  and `my_pattern` as necessary.

```
awk -v N=7 '{print}/my_pattern/&&--N<=0{exit}'
```

More cryptically, the following will also work:

```
awk -v N=7 '1;/my_pattern/&&--N<=0{exit}'
```

Both of the above actually stop on the Nth line containing the pattern, rather than the Nth occurrence of the pattern. If you want the Nth occurrence of the pattern:

```
awk -v N=7 -v M=my_pattern '1;(N-=gsub(M,""))<=0{exit}'
```

Eg:

```
printf %s\\n line1 "pattern in line 2" "pattern pattern in line 3" line4 pattern |
awk -v N=3 -v M=pattern '1;(N-=gsub(M,""))<=0{exit}'
```

=>

```
line1
pattern in line 2
pattern pattern in line 3
```

Comment: that is some very compact `awk`ing

Comment: @qwwqwwq if compact is what you like, you might like my answer :)

Comment: What if `my pattern` appears multiple times in one line? I tried `echo 'content1\nmy pattern\ncontent2 my pattern another my pattern\ncontent3\nmy pattern\n' | awk -v N=3 '1;/my pattern/&&--N<=0{exit}'`. I expect it outputs only the first 3 lines but instead it outputs all 5 lines.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this. The variable `N` is the max number of times. It will process the rest of the file but I don't think that's a big deal:

```
awk -vN=2 'n<N;/my_pattern/{++n}' file
```

Increment a counter every time the pattern is matched. Print the line as long as the counter is lower than the the variable `N`.

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted Answer, it's correct, more readable and more compact ...

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible, but it does exactly what you asked for.

```
cat input_file.txt \
  | tr '\n' '\0' \
  | sed -e 's:my_pattern:my_pattern\
:g' \
  | head -n$X \
  | tr -d '\n' \
  | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Notice the awesome use of an escaped newline within the sed pattern - I'm not sure if this can be avoided.

The idea here is to:

1. replace all newlines with `\0`
2. insert a newline after each pattern match
3. use `head -n X` to grab the first `X` matches
4. remove the newlines you inserted after the matches
5. replace the `\0` characters with newlines
6. (Optional) Cry in the shower.

Comment: You have a sick and twisted mind.  +1.  Not sure how many sed's besides GNU handle nuls.

Answer (score 0):

This would only print those lines if a pattern really exists along the way and not print everything if it's not found:

```
awk '{lines[NR]=$0}/pattern/{for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)print lines[i];exit}' file
```